# Read file and write file JSON

Tags: node.js, json, readfile, fs, writefile

In this, I am trying to make a hit counter where every time someone visits my site the variable will be read from the views.json file one is added to the number and then the .json will be updated with the new number. However when I tested it in a repl.it project I got an error saying

```
ReferenceError: writeFileSync is not defined
    at /home/runner/hit-counter/index.js:6:1
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:156:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
```

I don't know what this means if you know please tell me and how I may be able to fix it.

the reply project link:https://hit-counter.cohense.repl.run/

The JavaScript (ES6)

```
const fs = require('fs');
let views = fs.readFileSync('views.json');
views = JSON.parse(views);
views.total++;
let data = JSON.stringify(views, null, 2);
writeFileSync("views.json", data, finished);
function finished(err) {
  if (views = JSON.parse(views)) {
  console.log("Your view has been accounted for!")
} else {
  console.error("Error occured please reload the page =(")
}
};
```

the JSON

```
{
   "totalViews": 1
}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing with your approach?

Comment: Did you need help or have a question about your implementation?

Comment: Firstly you need a clear and unambiguous statement of your question. Also it is always good to provide as much context as possible. For example here you are specifying a Javascript file  but  you do not specify what version (ES6 for example) this is just an example of how you can add some helpful context.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, just fixed some errors.

Oh, you should use writeFileSync, to avoid that the file will not be edited at same time.

The question is, why don't you use a DB? It's a lot faster and fix concurrency writes.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var data = fs.readFileSync('views.json')
var views = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(views);

views.total = views.total + 1;

var data = JSON.stringify(views, null, 2)
writeFileSync("views.json", data, ()=>{
 console.log("Your View Has Been Accounted For!")
})
```

Comment: it should be fs.writeFileSync(...) instead of writeFileSync(...)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I did wrong I didn't use fs.

```
writeFileSync("views.json", data, finished);
```

When I just needed to do

```
fs.writeFileSync("views.json", data[,finished]);
```